# i want to copy strings from file into a variable 2d char

Tags: c, string, file

```
void lower_string(char s[]) {
int c = 0;

while (s[c] != '\0') {
  if (s[c] >= 'A' && s[c] <= 'Z') {
     s[c] = s[c] + 32;
  }
  c++;
 }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

if (argc<2){
    printf("Usage :WI_11SI2_12S17048.exe [nama file].txt \n");
    exit(0);
    }
const char *filename = argv[1];
FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
rewind(fp);
if (fp == NULL){
    printf("file doesn't exist.\n");
    exit(1);
    }
//CHECK WORDS COUNT AND MAX STRING LENGHT
char chr;
int word_count=0;
int chrcount=0;
int max_chrcount = 0; 
while ((chr=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
    if (isspace(chr)){
        if (chrcount > 0){
            word_count++;
            }
        max_chrcount = chrcount > max_chrcount ? chrcount : max_chrcount;
        chrcount=0;
        }else{
            chrcount++;
            }   
    }
rewind(fp); 
// SORTING ALL STRINGS BEFORE MAKING STRUCT
int t =0;
char buff[max_chrcount];
char buffer[word_count][max_chrcount];
while ((fscanf(fp,"%s",buff)) != EOF ){
    lower_string(buff);
    strcpy(buffer[t],buff);
    t++;
    }

for (int z =0 ; z < t ; z++){
    if (buffer[z] != NULL ){
        for (int b = z+1 ; b <= t ; b++){
            if(strcmp(buffer[z],buffer[b]) == 0){
                strcpy(buffer[b],"0");
                }
            }       
        }
    }
for(int z = 0 ; z <= t ;z++){
    if(buffer[z] != "0"){
        printf("%s\n",buffer[z]);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

TEXT in FILE :

```
SEPATU DALAM KOTAK
 kotak sepatu
 dalam kotak sepatu yang lain ada sandal dan kaos kaki
  sandal **berwarna  biru** milik ibu
 ayah dan ibu suka memakai sepatu
```

but when print, I get **berwarnabiru** and **biru** instead of **berwarna** and **biru**

i am sorry , anyone can help me ?
last , anyone can help me to store that in struct and make the output like this :

1. sepatu: 4
2. kotak: 3
3. dalam: 2
4. dan: 2
5. ibu: 2
6. sandal: 2
7. ada: 1
8. ayah: 1
9. berwarna: 1
10. biru: 1
11. kaki: 1
12. kaos: 1
13. lain: 1
14. memakai: 1
15. milik: 1
16. suka: 1
17. yang: 1

Comment: You don't print anything in the code snippet you posted. You need to post a [mcve]. The problem might be in `lower_string` or in any other part of your code you didn't post. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please have a look to [HowToAsk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question explaining what you tried and how you print the result that seems not the correct one

Comment: i'm sorry , i have edited my question

Comment: @MichaelWalz Hello , i have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot following problems:

1. The first `rewind(fp);` is useless and wrong. Useless because after opening the file, the file pointer it is already at the beginning, and wrong because if the file could not be opened for some reason, `fp` is `NULL` and `rewind(NULL)` is undefined behaviour, most likely you'll get a crash.
2. The computing of `word_count` is wrong, because you simply count the number of spaces, which is one less than the number of words, unless the file ends with at least one space: Example: `"One two three"`: two spaces here but three words.
3. `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, therefore you should have `int chr;`.
4. `if(buffer[z] != "0")` is always `false`. For comparing strings you need `strcmp`.
5. And finally: `max_chrcount` contains the maximum word length which is computed correctly, but you need one byte more to store the `NUL` terminator, therefore you need this:

---

```
char buff[max_chrcount + 1];
char buffer[word_count][max_chrcount + 1];
```

---

However there are most likely more problems.

nd I'm not quite sure what the purpose of `strcpy(buffer[b],"0")` is. Did you mean `buffer[b][0] = 0` ?